# How to set the title of a Navigation Bar programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, view, uinavigationbar

I have a Navigation Bar in a view, and I want to change its Navigation Item title programmatically.

How is this done?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

In your UIViewController

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"The title";
```

Comment: Yes, I would choose this as it only updates the navigationItem's title and not the toolbarItem's title.

Answer (score 34):

Swift 3 Version:

If you use a navigation bar without navigation controller, then you can try this:

```
navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Your Title"
```

Hope for help.

Answer (score 11):

In viewDidLoad

```
  self.title = @"Title";
```

Comment: My two cents :) This works, although if the vewcontroller is part of a toolbarcontroller. Then the toolbaritem's title is updated as well.

Answer (score 7):

Write the below code in `viewDidLoad` or may be better would be under `initWithNibName:`

```
  self.navigationItem.title = @"title";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UINavigationBar-SW1):

> The most common way to use a navigation bar is with a navigation
>   controller. You can also use a navigation bar as a standalone object
>   in your app.

So If you have a UINavigationController, all what you have to do to set the title of the navigation bar (as explained in all previous answers)

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"title";
```

But If you have a standalone navigation bar that is created programmatically within an object of UIViewController, You have to set the initial appearance of the navigation bar by creating the appropriate UINavigationItem objects and adding them to the navigation bar object stack i.e.

1. Create an instance of navigation bar (UINavigationBar)
2. Create an instance of navigation bar item (UINavigationItem) that manages the buttons and views to be displayed in a UINavigationBar object. Note that you set the title at this step.
3. (Optional Step) Add right/left buttons (instances of UIBarButtonItem) to the navigation bar item.

Sample of Objective-C Code for the mentioned steps:

```
UINavigationBar* navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)];

/* Create navigation item object & set the title of navigation bar. */
UINavigationItem* navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.shoppingItem.name];

/* Create left button item. */
UIBarButtonItem* cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(onTapCancel:)];
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBtn;

/* Create left button item. */
UIBarButtonItem* doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(onTapDone:)];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneBtn;

/* Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar.*/
[navbar setItems:@[navItem]];

/* add navigation bar to the root view.*/
[self.view addSubview:navbar];
```

For Swift version of the standalone navigation bar, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448766/adding-navigation-bar-programmatically-ios#answer-21448861).

Answer (score 7):

In your UIViewController's viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationItem.title = "The title";  //In swift 4
```

or

you can just

```
self.title = "The title"
```

will do the trick

you can also put the above statement in the app delegate to replicate globally.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitle:@"Titlet"];
```

Comment: You can, but why would you? The view controller doesn't know that's it's on top, so this seems likely to cause confusion. `self.title` is much more precise.

Answer (score 3):

This code did not work for me

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Title here";
```

But this worked.

```
self.title = "Title Name"
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked many solutions but only this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use it in ViewDidLoad method

**Format :**

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UINavigationItem *navigationItem; // Created on-demand so that a view controller may customize its navigation appearance.
```

**Example :**

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Title here";
```

Answer (score 0):

very important note : make sure you make the changes that mentioned above in parent view Controller's viewDidLoad method, or parents navigation bar in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might get a case where you are updating the title and it is not causing any effect, this can be when you have a custom view on the `topItem` therefore you might want to update it like this: `(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView as? UILabel)?.text = "My Happy New Title"`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift:**

```
self.navigationItem.title = "The title;
```

**Objective c**

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"The title";
```

**SwiftUI**

```
.navigationBarTitle("Your Title Here")
```