# Adding Navigation Bar programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I am trying to make an App with a Navigation Bar (Back button, title, etc) and a Tab Bar (Toolbar on the bottom). I am using subviews so I don't have to worry about the status bar, navigation bar, tab bar heights, etc.  But I think it's causing me trouble because I can't seem to figure out how to setup the Nav and Tab Bars.

Here is what I have. What am I doing wrong?

AppDelegate.h

```
(default for single view app)
```

AppDelegate.m

```
(default for single view app)
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *contentSubview;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)loadView{}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.contentSubview = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.contentSubview.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [view addSubview:self.contentSubview];
    self.view = view;
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
    {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.contentSubview.frame = CGRectMake(
                                       0,
                                       self.topLayoutGuide.length,
                                       CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame),
                                       CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)-self.topLayoutGuide.length-self.bottomLayoutGuide.length
                                       );
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: What does any of this code have to do with adding a navigation bar or tool bar? Are you trying to add just a navigation bar and tool bar, or do you want a navigation controller? What are you tying to accomplish?

Comment: I guess that's where I'm confused. I want to add a navigation bar and toolbar. But I am using subviews, so I wasn't sure if I had to do something different.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
 UINavigationBar* navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];

UINavigationItem* navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"karthik"];
// [navbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
UIBarButtonItem* cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(onTapCancel:)];
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBtn;

UIBarButtonItem* doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(onTapDone:)];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneBtn;

[navbar setItems:@[navItem]];
[self.view addSubview:navbar];
}


-(void)onTapDone:(UIBarButtonItem*)item{

}

-(void)onTapCancel:(UIBarButtonItem*)item{

}
```

**Swift3**

```
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height:44)) // Offset by 20 pixels vertically to take the status bar into account

    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


    // Create a navigation item with a title
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "Title"

    // Create left and right button for navigation item
     let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style:   .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.btn_clicked(_:)))

    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)

    // Create two buttons for the navigation item
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

    // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    // Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)




func btn_clicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Do something
}
```

**Swift**

```
 // Create the navigation bar
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)) // Offset by 20 pixels vertically to take the status bar into account

    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigationBar.delegate = self;

    // Create a navigation item with a title
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "Title"

    // Create left and right button for navigation item
    let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style:   UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "btn_clicked:")
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)

    // Create two buttons for the navigation item
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

    // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    // Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)


  func btn_clicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  // Do something
 }
```

Comment: I got this to work and show a navigation bar. However setting the title and items has proved to be difficult.

Comment: I also want to setup a tab bar with icons too.

Comment: @boxmatic how did you set up the title and items?

Answer (score 4):

xib method:

tutorial from [here](http://maybelost.com/2010/12/putting-a-uinavigationcontroller-within-a-uitabbarcontroller/)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Create the PlainViewController (and give it a title)
    PlainViewController *plainView = [[PlainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlainViewController" bundle:nil];
    [plainView setTitle:@"PlainView"];

    // Create the NavRootView controller (and give it a title)
    NavRootView *navRoot = [[NavRootView alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavRootView" bundle:nil];
    [navRoot setTitle:@"NavRoot"];

    // Create our navigation controller using our NavRootView as it's root view
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navRoot];

    // Make an array containing our plain view controller and our navigation controller
    NSArray *viewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainView, navController, nil];

    // Release the views and nav controller
    [plainView release];
    [navRoot release];
    [navController release];

    // Create our tab bar controller
    UITabBarController *tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    // Tell the tab bar controller to use our array of views
    [tabbarController setViewControllers:viewArray];

    // Finally, add the tabbar controller as a subview of the app window
    [window addSubview:[tabbarController view]];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

only code:

[howto-implement-uinavigationcontroller-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically](http://www.xdracco.net/howto-implement-uinavigationcontroller-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically/)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /* Initialize window view */
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    /* Initialize tab bar controller, add tabs controllers */
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [self initializeTabBarItems];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return (YES);
}

- (NSArray *)initializeTabBarItems
{
    NSArray * retval;

    /* Initialize view controllers */
    ViewController1 * viewController1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
    ViewController2 * viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    ViewController3 * viewController3 = [[ViewController3 alloc] init];
    ViewController4 * viewController4 = [[ViewController4 alloc] init];
    ViewController5 * viewController5 = [[ViewController5 alloc] init];

    /* Initialize navigation controllers */
    UINavigationController * navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    UINavigationController * navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    UINavigationController * navigationController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];
    UINavigationController * navigationController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4];
    UINavigationController * navigationController5 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController5];



    /* Stuff Navigation Controllers into return value */
    retval = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,viewController2,viewController3,viewController4,viewController5,nil];



    return (retval);
}
```

storyboard:

[storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

[image]

Comment: This tutorial is kinda old. I tried to use the only code version and I haven't been able to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C

```
UINavigationBar* navigationbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarFrame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
UINavigationItem* navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
[navigationbar setItems:@[navigationItem]];
[self.view addSubview:navigationbar];
```

In Swift

```
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height, width: view.frame.size.width, height:44))
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "Title"
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.

The context: Here is a view controller that is presented to edit a user's bio information.

```
import UIKit

class EditBioController: UIViewController {

    // What you need are these two classes. One is a navigation bar,
    // and the other will hold the items that are in the navigation bar.
    private var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
    private var customNavigationItem: UINavigationItem!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Create a navigation bar with the width of the view, and the standard height of 44.
        navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 44))
        
        // Initialize the UINavigationItem class. The name is a bit confusing, because as you'll see -
        // we add multiple items to the one 'UINavigationItem.'
        customNavigationItem = UINavigationItem()
        customNavigationItem.title = "Edit Bio"
        
        let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(selectorX))
        customNavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
        
        let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(selectorX))
        customNavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
        
        // Add the items to the navigation bar.
        navigationBar.items = [customNavigationItem]
        // Add the navigation bar to the view.
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
        
        
    }
    
    @objc func selectorX() {
        
    }
    
}
```

Here's what this produces:
[image]

Answer (score -3):

Swift version, add this in viewDidLoad:

```
var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "doneButton:")
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton
```

And this in your View Controller class

```
func doneButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    println(111)
}
```

Comment: The question was about adding a Navigation Bar and not how to add handlers for the bar button items