# iOS: adding UINavigationBar to UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I'm adding a UINavigationBar to UITableView programmatically but the UINavigationBar is blocking the first tableview cell.

Here is my code:

```
self.table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.table.delegate = self;
    self.table.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.table];
     UINavigationBar *navBar = [[ UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
        navBar.topItem.title = @"tableVIew";
        [self.view addSubview:navBar];
```

My question is how can add the UINavigationBar without blocking any of the tableview cells.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't add the nav bar to the table view. Why not put the view controller in a navigation controller? Then you got the nav bar properly and you can push and pop other view controllers as needed.

Comment: @rmaddy can you post how to do it?

Comment: Please read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" in the docs for everything you need to know on subject.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say tableView is in "ViewController". Now in-order to call view controller use the below code:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
```

This will add a navigation to your view controller. You need not need to use add subview to add a navigation bar.

Comment: this implemented in the view controller?

Comment: Not in a view controller but while calling a controller. So here instead of "ViewController" it would be your controller name.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add the `UINavigationBar` to `UITableView`. You should add it to `UIViewController` instead of adding to any other `UIView` element. You can find a question-answer about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448766/adding-navigation-bar-programmatically-ios-7).

Also in your code, you set your `table`'s frame is wrong. It should be

```
CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-50)
```

Comment: I add UINavigationBar to UITableView [self.table addSubview:navBar]; but still is blocking the first tableviewcell.

Comment: You shouldn't add it to UITableView. You should add it to your UIViewController

Comment: can you post and example?

Comment: There is an example in the link in my answer

Comment: in your link is showing the same thing I doing "[self.view addSubview:navbar];"

Comment: I just realized, you set your frames wrong actually. In tableView allocation you should use CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 50)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you probably shouldn't construct your layout this way.
But if you are intent on doing it this way, you can always set the `tableView.contentInset` property to add an inset to the top of the `tableView` to account for the height of the navigationBar.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(navBarframe.size.height, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your tableviewController's viewdidload func ,Just add a line of code . I assume this will work.

```
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdge.None
```