# How to get rid of the space between the navigation bar and the top of the phone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar

I am not using a navigation controller control this view because the navigation controller forces me to use segues that I do not want to use (and I'm not sure how to over write those segues, I've tried multiple things but they always lead to a crash); although, the good thing about using the navigation controller, among many other things, is that there is no space between the navigation bar and the top of the phone.

However, because I want to use my own custom segues, I just added a navigation bar to my view controller. The problem this caused is as follows:

[image]

There is this space between the navigation bar and the top of the phone. And I do not want the space there. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: You have added custom navigation bar that's why this issue is created.

Comment: @El CaptainI don't necessarily want it hidden. I just want the space between the bar and the phone to be gone.

Comment: Change the bar's Y position to 20 if you want to add the custom navigation. because status bar size is 20.

Comment: navigation must be 64px instead of 44.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create navigation bar programatically this way:

```
// Create the navigation bar
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)) // Offset by 20 pixels vertically to take the status bar into account

navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

// Create a navigation item with a title
let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
navigationItem.title = "Profile"

// Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

// Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

Result:

[image]

Space is not there anymore.

Original Post: [Adding Navigation Bar programmatically iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448766/adding-navigation-bar-programmatically-ios-7)

**UPDATE:**

If you want to add buttons add this code:

```
// Create left and right button for navigation item
let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "LeftButton", style:   UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "leftClicked:")
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "RightButton", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "rightClicked:")

// Create two buttons for the navigation item
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

And here is helper method:

```
func leftClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Do something
    println("Left Button Clicked")
}

func rightClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Do something
    println("Right Button Clicked")
}
```

And final code will be:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
        // Create the navigation bar
        let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)) // Offset by 20 pixels vertically to take the status bar into account

        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        // Create a navigation item with a title
        let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
        navigationItem.title = "Profile"

        // Create left and right button for navigation item
        let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "LeftButton", style:   UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "leftClicked:")
        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "RightButton", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "rightClicked:")

        // Create two buttons for the navigation item
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

        // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
        navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

        // Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
    }

    func leftClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Do something
        println("Left Button Clicked")
    }

    func rightClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Do something
        println("Right Button Clicked")
    }

}
```

Comment: @iAshish because then profile will be too close to the time. And they will look smushed.

Comment: @Dharmesh Kheni But there is still a space between the phone and the navigation bar... I want the place where the carrier, the time, and the battery life to be all the same color as the navigation bar color.

Comment: Haha. Just kidding. I will do my research first.

Comment: Check my updated code.Hope that is what you need..:)

Comment: I just changed one of the parameters that you provided, namely, the 44, to 60. And it changed it for me.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is like amazing!

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Comment: One thing though, when I tap the left button, nothing seems to happen... Namely, nothing is printing to the console.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using standalone `UINavigationBar` just because you could not work out how segue works, my first advise would be to use `UINavigationController` as it gives you so much for free.

Per Apple Docs:

> When you use a navigation bar as a standalone object, you are
>   responsible for providing its contents. Unlike other types of views,
>   you do not add subviews to a navigation bar directly. Instead, you use
>   a navigation item (an instance of the UINavigationItem class) to
>   specify what buttons or custom views you want displayed. A navigation
>   item has properties for specifying views on the left, right, and
>   center of the navigation bar and for specifying a custom prompt
>   string.

If you still want to explore this path then you need to implement `-positionForBar:` of the `UINavigationBarDelegate` like this:

```
func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
  return .TopAttached
}
```

You might have to set the `tintColor` as well to make it look aligned with status bar:

```
let viewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:20, width: viewWidth, height:44))
navBar.barTintColor = UIColor .lightGrayColor()
navBar.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(navBar)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @iAshish. I didn't see the tag :). Corrected my code!

Comment: Welcome. Please correct your width too 320 only is not good. iPhone 6, 6 Plus, 6s and 6s Plus are in market now :)

Comment: Missed that in a rush to fix it :). @iAshish