# App page header is split in half on iPhone 14 Pro

Tags: ios, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

The problem:

[image: the problem screenshot image here]

When I test with Xcode's debugging tools I don't see the problem, but when I test the app through Test Flight I see the app's page header is split in half on iPhone 14 Pro.

How do I solve this problem? Do I need to fix this from my code side or do I need to report a bug to Apple?

```swift
navigationItem.title = "Settings"
navigationItem.backButtonTitle = ""
navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(rgb:purpleColour)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of the space between the navigation bar and the top of the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644799/how-to-get-rid-of-the-space-between-the-navigation-bar-and-the-top-of-the-phone)

Comment: I have this problem just only when I test on apple test flight.