# Add navigation bar within self

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm looking to add a **`UINavigationBar`** in a **`UIViewController`**. I know that I can add a **navigation bar** in **Storyboard** and I can also trigger it using a segue and also doing it manually by adding a **width** and **height**. Instead of doing it manually, I want to do it inside of the class without adding the **height** and **width**. The **navigation bar** behaves naturally as if it is triggered by a segue. So something like **`self.navigationController`** would work. **`self.navigationController`** would present the **`UINavigationBar`**

And any other in I need to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code for swift2.X for swift3 use this link [Adding Navigation Bar programmatically iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448766/adding-navigation-bar-programmatically-ios)

```
 // Create the navigation bar
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)) // Offset by 20 pixels vertically to take the status bar into account

    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigationBar.delegate = self;

    // Create a navigation item with a title
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "Title"

    // Create left and right button for navigation item
    let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style:   UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "btn_clicked:")
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)

    // Create two buttons for the navigation item
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

    // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    // Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)


  func btn_clicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  // Do something
 }
```

Comment: although this work the issues come with device rotation. even though I can use constraints using bar barItems and title constraints become another issue.

Comment: This should be possible because it can be added it by dragging it in user interface but i wanted to do it programatically.