# Add navigationController to specif viewController programmatically without storyboard swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to add `navigationController` to just only for `HomeViewController` for example. I know how to do it from `AppDelegate` and like this below

```
let navBar = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController())
self.present(navBar, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is there another way that I can add `navigationController` inside `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`?

Edited:

My logic is when I pressed Login button which is the code below. Then it will present `SWRevealViewController`

```
@IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: Any) {    
    let frontViewController = HomeViewController()
    let rearViewController  = TableViewController()
    let swRevealVC = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearViewController, frontViewController: frontViewController)
    swRevealVC?.toggleAnimationType = SWRevealToggleAnimationType.easeOut
    swRevealVC?.toggleAnimationDuration = 0.30

    self.present(swRevealVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I just only want to set `navigationController` to `HomeViewController`

Comment: What is your purpose? And how you will go to HomeViewController, if you are not setting it in app delegate?

Comment: You can't add `UINavigationController` inside `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` but you can add an `UINavigationBar`. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448766/adding-navigation-bar-programmatically-ios

Comment: I updated my question with more information

Comment: @SeizeDuh did you try to use `let frontViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController())`

Comment: @trungduc It works with `let frontViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
let frontViewController = HomeViewController()
```

with

```
let frontViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Look below code hope it works for you...

This will be in App delegate

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: REMEMBER_ME) {
   let menuVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SideMenuViewController())
   let loginVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DashboardViewController())
   let revealViewController = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: menuVC, frontViewController: loginVC)
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
   window?.rootViewController = revealViewController
} else {
   window?.rootViewController = LoginViewController()
}
```

This will be in your login action

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
    let menuVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SideMenuViewController())
    let loginVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DashboardViewController())
    let revealViewController = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: menuVC, frontViewController: loginVC)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    window.rootViewController = revealViewController
}
```