# How to create a navigation bar in a view controller using xib programmatically in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, xcode12.3

can somebody please help me to solve this, I didn't post my code because im confused with some codes so I need a set of code to create a navigation bar and navigation items in a view controller without navigation controller...kindly help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21449603/8013132

To hide navigation bar:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

To show it:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Comment: thank you so much...the link which u attached https://stackoverflow.com/a/21449603/8013132 helps a lot...thank you so much...