# Updating UILabel from another View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Hi i am kind of stuck at the moment as to sending UILabel data across from one view controller to another coming from a collection view cell. Here is my current code of which i get no errors? May seem obvious to someone who knows what they are doing but do i need to somehow declare on the second view controller that i am setting the UILabel from another VC?

Here is my current code as follows:

GroupsViewController.m

```
#import "GroupsViewController.h"
#import "GroupsHomeViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GroupsHomeSegue" sender:indexPath];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GroupsHomeSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [[self.GroupsCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]firstObject];
        if(indexPath !=nil)
        {
            NSString *selectedImage = arrayOfImages [indexPath.item]; //collect image
            GroupsHomeViewController *groupsHomeVC = segue.destinationViewController; //set D.V.C
            groupsHomeVC.logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed: selectedImage]; //set image
            groupsHomeVC.groupLabel.text = arrayOfDescriptions[indexPath.item ]; //set text

        }
    }
}
```

GroupsHomeViewController.h

```
@interface GroupsHomeViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *logoImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *logoImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *groupLabel;
@end
```

GroupsHomeViewController.m

```
#import "GroupsHomeViewController.h"

@interface GroupsHomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation GroupsHomeViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.logoImageView.image = self.logoImage;
}
```

Many Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: does this code correctly set logoImage on the DVC?

Comment: Yeah it sets the image perfectly no problems, I just can't get it to set the label on the secondary view controller

Comment: I assume you hooked up your IBOutlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because At this time, the `GroupsHomeViewController` is not loaded in the memory yet, that's why you are facing this issue.
Instead of directly passing value to UILabel, try passing text using `NSString`. Declare

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *valueToPass;
```

in `GroupsHomeViewController` . Then pass value to string using below code

```
NSString *selectedImage = arrayOfImages [indexPath.item]; //collect image
GroupsHomeViewController *groupsHomeVC = segue.destinationViewController; //set D.V.C
groupsHomeVC.logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed: selectedImage]; //set image
// pass string to next viewController's NSString object.            
groupsHomeVC.valueToPass = arrayOfDescriptions[indexPath.item ];
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` of `GroupsHomeViewController` ,set string on `UILabel` like this `self.groupLabel.text=self.valueToPass`. Try doing this.

Comment: Would it also be possible to use the same string and set it as the view controller title on the top bar?

Comment: Yes, you can simply pass this string as navigation bar title.

Comment: Please could you be so kind and provide me with me an example?

Comment: You can refer this link. Will surely help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154237/how-to-set-the-title-of-a-navigation-bar-programatically

Comment: Thank you very much for all off your help!

Answer (score 1):

First thing in GroupsHomeViewController.h create one property as

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *descriptionName;
```

then update your method to

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GroupsHomeSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [[self.GroupsCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]firstObject];
        if(indexPath !=nil)
        {
            NSString *selectedImage = arrayOfImages [indexPath.item]; //collect image
            GroupsHomeViewController *groupsHomeVC = segue.destinationViewController; //set D.V.C
            groupsHomeVC.logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed: selectedImage]; //set image
            groupsHomeVC.descriptionName = arrayOfDescriptions[indexPath.item ]; //set text

        }
    }
}
```

Now in GroupsHomeViewController.m update this

```
#import "GroupsHomeViewController.h"

@interface GroupsHomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation GroupsHomeViewController
@synthesize descriptionName;
-(void)viewDidLoad{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self. groupLabel.text = descriptionName;
}
```

This will surely help. In your case text is assigning to label but when you move to lifecycle methods of GroupsHomeViewController gets called. So here your UILabel is getting initialised and your are setting text before it so its not displaying it.

Creating NSString property will surely help you out.