# Swift change tabBar title after touching a tabbar item

Tags: swift

I have app with a tabBar and Navigation controller.

How can I change the tabBar title (visible in top application's window) when I touch it in tabbar?

For example i have these items in tabbar:

- Pizza
- Beer
- Orange
- Apple

After I click pizza I want to have pizza in the title app in the top menu.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the title of a Navigation Bar programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154237/how-to-set-the-title-of-a-navigation-bar-programmatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Depending on your implementation, one of the below methods should work for you.**

```
self.navigationItem.title = "title"
```

or

```
self.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "title"
```

> If you are using a custom tabbar made with UIButtons and container
>   view, then add this to the button action or if you are using a native
>   UITabBarController, then set it's delegate to self and call this on
>   the didSelectViewController delegate method of the UITabBarController.

.

EDIT

After seeing your code, you need to use this property :

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Profile"
```

and call this in every view controller's viewWillAppear, example for **ProfileViewController**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Profile"
    }
```

Also, make sure that in storyboard, you set the view controller's class to the respective code class like :

[image: add class to view controller in storyboard]

and remove the text from the custom navigation bar you used:

[image: remove the text from navigation bar]

Comment: where to add it? To viewcontroller selected items from tabbar?

Comment: if you are using a custom tabbar made with UIButtons, then add this to the action listener or if you are using a native UITabBarController, then set it's delegate to self and call this on the didSelectViewController delegate method of the UITabBarController

Comment: This is my source code: https/we.tl/6PW31OJwmi . I have problem with animated tab bar. Could you take a look?

Comment: cool, please upvote as well ! and for using the button, use a similar logic to find the button like self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems!.first!